# Word for a job with frequent location changes

Tags: word-request, adjectives

Which adjective word can I use to describe my friend's father's military job in which he need to frequently resettle in a new place after every 2-3 years?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's the word [***transient***](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/transient?q=transient), but I **wouldn't** use that to describe a military job. (I think *transient* implies something less structured than a military position – when I hear *'transient worker'*, I think of something more along the lines of migrant agricultural work, and not something associated with a larger entity like a federal government.)

I'm not sure there's a single adjective that accurately expresses the sentiment you're after. Words such as *unsteady* are even more misleading than *transient*. I'd be inclined to say:

> It's a job that requires frequent moves.

and leave it at that.

Comment: +1 But it may be that the soldier's family feels something more like *It's a job that requires a **nomadic** lifestyle*.

Comment: @StoneyB: You could say that, if you didn't mind exaggerating. I made several moves when I was in the military, but I still bought houses and settled into the community. However, I did know one lieutenant who was an instructor and traveled to teach courses on-site. She definitely lived as a nomad – or, as is sometimes said, "lived out of a suitcase." Deployments aside, though, I think _nomad_ would be hyperbole for many soldiers and airmen.

Answer (score 2):

I know. 
None of the below are adjectives.

The only appropriate adjective, transient, has already been suggested by J.R

I know.
I have **not** answered the OP question.

However, these are all expressions which can be used to talk about any person or any family that often moves to a different town or location. I think they are useful to know.

> to be frequently relocated
>
> to be (constantly) on the move
>
> to be often transferred
>
> to have no fixed abode
>
> to be temporarily based
>
> to flit from one town to another
>
> to have temporary lodgings

Answer (score 2):

You could consider the adjective [*itinerant*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/itinerant), meaning "traveling from place to place."  However, to my ear it has a slight connotation of unreliability, as if the person wasn't successful in any one place for long and was forced to move on.  *Requires frequent moves* is probably safest, and easiest to understand.